# Let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure. Show, that if $A \subset B$ has an interior point, then $\mu(A) > 0$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A \subset B$ be a Lebesgue measurable set with at least one interior point.

1. Show, that $\mu(A) > 0$
2. For any $0 \le \alpha < \mu(A)$ there is a set $A_{\alpha} \subset A$ such, that $\mu(A_{\alpha}) = \alpha$

---

**My proof**

*ad 1.*

$x \in A$ is an interior point, if there exists a neighborhood $U(x)$ such that $U(x) \subset A$ and $U(x) \neq \varnothing$

Because we assume, that $A$ has at least one interior point, then this means that there exists at least one non-empty neighborhood $U(x) \subset A$

Using the properties of our Lebesgue measure, we get, that $\mu (U(x)) \le \mu(A)$. But because $U(x) \neq \varnothing$, then we get $0 < \mu (U(x)) \le \mu(A)$

*ad 2.*

Let's say, that $A = A_1^1 + A_1^2$ such, that $\mu(A_1^1) = \mu (A_1^2) = \frac{1}{2} \mu(A)$

We repeat this process over and over again (so we'd have $A_1^1 = A_{2,1}^1 + A_{2,1}^2$ such that $\mu( A_{2,1}^1) = \mu ( A_{2,1}^2) = \frac{1}{2} A_1^1 = \frac{1}{4} A$ etc.), until we have divided our set $A$ into such small pieces, that we can construct our set $A_{\alpha}$ with measure $\alpha$

For example: Let $\alpha = \frac{3}{4} \mu(A)$, then our $A_{\alpha} = A_1^1 \cup A_{2,1}^1$ for example.

---

Are my proofs correct? Do they need extra commentary? Can I somehow express them in a more abstract and mathematical way (especially *ad 2.*)?

Comment: Are $A$, $B$ subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ or subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no information about this whatsoever

Answer (score 1):

For part 1 you have to prove that $\mu(U(x)) > 0$. For part 2 you have to specify how you were able to decompose your $A$ into $A_1^1$, $A_1^2$, and you have to show how to find $A_{\alpha}$ for all $\alpha \in [0, \mu(A))$, not just $\alpha = \frac{3}{4}$. It's not obvious to me how to do number $2$ based on what you've written, say for $\alpha = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\mu(A)$.

Comment: Isn't $\mu (U (x)) > 0$ obvious, because $U(x) \neq \varnothing$? What I mean with part 2 is that you divide the set $A$ into such small sets that if you want to have a set $A_{\alpha} \subset A$ such that $\mu (A_{\alpha}) = \alpha$, then you just take a specific sum of those small sets (like my short example with $\frac{3}{4} \mu(A)$

Comment: There are sets $S \neq \emptyset$ such that $\mu(S) = 0$, e.g. any countable set $S$. How do you divide $A$ into such small sets? What is the proof that such a division exists?

Comment: If we assume that we are in $\mathbb{R}$, then it's pretty easy to prove that $\mu (U(x)) = 0 \: \Leftrightarrow \: U(x) = \text{ singleton, or }\varnothing$ and that we are able to divide our set $A$ into small sets.

Comment: @anon That's not true. $\mu(\mathbb{Q}) = 0$, and $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable. For an uncountable set of measure $0$, the Cantor set is an example. To prove 1, note that if $U$ is a nonempty open set, then $U$ contains an open cube $Q$ of positive side length $s$. Hence $\mu(U) \geq \mu(Q) = s^n > 0$. If it's easy to prove, then include the argument (or at least a sketch) in your proof.

Answer (score 0):

Part 1 is easy, so I skip it. I work on Part 2.
I assume that you are working on $\mathbb{R}$ rather than $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.
Define $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=\mu\left([-x,x]\cap A\right)=\int_{-x}^{x}1_{A}d\mu$.
Clearly $f$ is continuous and $f(x)\rightarrow\mu(A)$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$ by continuity
of measure. Moreover, $f(0)=0$. Now, given $\alpha$ with $0<\alpha<\mu(A)$,
we can choose a sufficiently large $x$ such that $f(x)>\alpha$.
Observe that $f(0)<\alpha<f(x)$. By intermediate value theorem, there
exists $x'\in(0,x)$ such that $f(x')=\alpha$. Define $A_{\alpha}=[-x',x']\cap A$,
then $\mu(A_{\alpha})=f(x')=\alpha$.

Comment: But my proof for part 1 is alright? To part 2: The condition would be $0 \le \alpha < \mu (A)$, not $0 < \alpha$ if that's important somehow?

Comment: If $\alpha=0$, just choose $A_\alpha =\emptyset$.

Comment: So what about my proof for ad 1? I think I need to assume here that $U(x)$ is a ball $K(x, \varepsilon)$ to make sure that (in $\mathbb{R}$) its measure is greater than zero?